# How to achieve this image layout in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, responsive

I want to achieve this layout of 5 images where image 1 is large on left and the remaining 4 are to the right in their own column as shown in picture. I want this layout to stay the same for all screen sizes except a very small screen size. Left column and right column height should be same for all screen sizes.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you're wanting to create is a css grid. They are fairly straight forward to create and very responsive. This is a tutorial on how too make your own custom grid and how to tailor it to your needs ([YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plRcoRqLriw)). Being able to make grids is a very useful skill.

Comment: Thanks a lot for introducing me to grids. working like charm.Thanks for your help again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use CSS grid to implement it. CSS tutorial refers to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_grid.asp).

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
  grid-gap: 0 5px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 150px 150px 150px 150px 150px;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .grid-container>img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .item1 {
    grid-column-start: unset;
    grid-column-end: unset;
    grid-row-start: unset;
    grid-row-end: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <img class="item1" src="https://picsum.photos/id/500/600/600">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/600/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/700/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/800/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/900/200/150">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Grids is a game changer.

Comment: Glad that I am able to help.